# Switching a Sink Light

Tags: wiring

I have 4 can lights in the main area of the kitchen, and 1 light over the sink. They are all controlled by two 3way switches. I want to add a new switch adjacent to the sink to control just the light over the sink separate from the main area can lights. The wires going to the light over the sink is the end of the circuit, black, white and ground.

Thx for any help,

Steve

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the light over the sink gets its power from the other lights.

Just adding a switch will only allow you to turn it off.

Will need to get power from another source(an outlet) to new switch to the light.

Capping off the black/white wires from the other lights to have full control of that light.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the input